# Emoji doesn't work on my secondary page but on my main page it does

Tags: html

On my main page, I have an emoji and it works fine. But I have the exact same code on my seond one and it does not work

I have tried looking for an answer but no else seems to have this problem

This bit is my main page that the code works on:

```
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<link rel="icon" 
    href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1G624t-8tJG_l29sdQ4COazA_c69aBB3Q&authuser=0">
<title>Game ðŸ‘ Reveiw</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a>
  <a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a>
  <a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a>
</div>
<h1>Game ðŸ‘ Reveiw </h1>

<h4><a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a> |
<a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a> |
<a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a></h4>
<br>
<br>
<div class="center">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium quam
 libero. Etiam fringilla auctor accumsan. Aenean tellus ex,<br>
convallis non enim at, pharetra accumsan ligula. 
mi vel est bibendum rhoncus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br>
Sed ullamcorper feugiat quam, ac mattis quam finibus eu. Fusce eget justo a odio 
ultrices efficitur. Donec elementum purus sed iaculis rutrum.<br>
Praesent ornare laoreet faucibus. Suspendisse consequat, nisi eu convallis vestibulum,<br>
nibh est imperdiet nulla, ut suscipit dolor ex scelerisque neque. Morbi sed mi 
cursus, mattis velit a, laoreet velit. Donec nulla felis, scelerisque at sem 
</div>

<footer>Game ðŸ‘ Reveiw</footer>
```

This is my other page(connected to it) and the footer code doesn't work:

```
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<title>Portal 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_portal_2.css">
<link rel="icon" 
    href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Pp9iytPYBcUg7fOIsH6QuiyM7JeL9SKK&authuser=0">
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a>
  <a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a>
  <a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a>
</div>

<h1>Portal 2:</h1>
<h4><a href="website.html">Home</a></h4><br>

<div class="center">
Portal 2 is a game for those lonely friday nights where you need that comfort of
 Wheatley<br>
and the engaging aspect of the game. 
while being relaxing and funny at times. With my times playing Portal 2, I got 
sucked into a<br>
world where there is no competition and the only skill you need is problem 
solving. In this<br>
game you are a test subject with a ‘Portal Gun’ that creates portals to complete 
challenges.<br>
The challenges get harder and harder as you progress.<br>
Overall this game is amazing and would highly recommend it.<br>
<img width="400" 
    src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13djQKInGDpkkmiUEj8PwM-h-dkWsOHDt"title="nice"><br>
</div>

<footer>Game ðŸ‘ Reveiw</footer>
```

Expected output to be an emoji but got some weird code

Comment: Which one is the emoji?

Comment: In the 2nd piece of code, please place a space here: `src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13djQKInGDpkkmiUEj8PwM-h-dkWsOHDt"`**PLEASE PUT A SPACE HERE**`title="nice"`

Comment: Make sure all styles and title are in the `head`. Please test with those changes then come back and update your html whether it worked or not.

Comment: Same question as @GROVER.

Comment: If that's your literal HTML content, then you're missing the `<body>` tag, which means your document is invalid. Invalid documents are handled differently, depending on browser, but I would start with fixing that, since it can affect how the browser renders CSS and whatnot.

Comment: Where is the emoji in the first page?

Answer (score 0):

According to this well written article (https://www.kirupa.com/html5/emoji.htm) , there are two ways you can insert an emoji, by copying and pasting the emoji itself into your code or by grabbing the codepoints (https://emojipedia.org) for it and pasting that in your html.

Try using the emoji codepoints. If you load the below files in your browser, you can see that the emoji appears consistently in the browser on both pages.

page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
       </head>
       <body>
       <link rel="icon" 
           href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1G624t-8tJG_l29sdQ4COazA_c69aBB3Q&authuser=0">
       <title>Game &#x1F354 Reveiw</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       <div class="topnav">
         <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
         <a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a>
         <a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a>
         <a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a>
       </div>
       <h1>Game &#x1F354 Reveiw </h1>

       <h4><a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a> |
       <a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a> |
       <a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a></h4>
       <br>
       <br>
       <div class="center">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium quam
        libero. Etiam fringilla auctor accumsan. Aenean tellus ex,<br>
       convallis non enim at, pharetra accumsan ligula. 
       mi vel est bibendum rhoncus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
       elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br>
       Sed ullamcorper feugiat quam, ac mattis quam finibus eu. Fusce eget justo a odio 
       ultrices efficitur. Donec elementum purus sed iaculis rutrum.<br>
       Praesent ornare laoreet faucibus. Suspendisse consequat, nisi eu convallis vestibulum,<br>
       nibh est imperdiet nulla, ut suscipit dolor ex scelerisque neque. Morbi sed mi 
       cursus, mattis velit a, laoreet velit. Donec nulla felis, scelerisque at sem 
       </div>
    </body>

       <footer>Game &#x1F354 Reveiw</footer>
       </html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
       </head>
       <title>Portal 2</title>
       <body>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_portal_2.css">
       <link rel="icon" 
           href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Pp9iytPYBcUg7fOIsH6QuiyM7JeL9SKK&authuser=0">
       <div class="topnav">
         <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
         <a href="portal_2.html">Portal 2</a>
         <a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a>
         <a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a>
       </div>

       <h1>Portal 2:</h1>
       <h4><a href="website.html">Home</a></h4><br>

       <div class="center">
       Portal 2 is a game for those lonely friday nights where you need that comfort of
        Wheatley<br>
       and the engaging aspect of the game. 
       while being relaxing and funny at times. With my times playing Portal 2, I got 
       sucked into a<br>
       world where there is no competition and the only skill you need is problem 
       solving. In this<br>
       game you are a test subject with a ‘Portal Gun’ that creates portals to complete 
       challenges.<br>
       The challenges get harder and harder as you progress.<br>
       Overall this game is amazing and would highly recommend it.<br>
       <img width="400" 
           src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13djQKInGDpkkmiUEj8PwM-h-dkWsOHDt"title="nice"><br>
       </div>
    </body>

       <footer>Game &#x1F354 Reveiw</footer>
       </html>
```